# Adding animation delay does not change effects

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a simple slider and I have added `animation: slide 0.5s forwards; animation-delay: 2s;` to buttons but it doesn't change anything. My goal is to make transition effects on images, to show next image slowly from right side to left. And when showing back image from left side to right slowly. I hope you understand what I mean. But it doesn't change anything. https://jsfiddle.net/9t3cbese/7/

js:

```
var imageCount = 1;
var total = 10;

function photo(x) {
    var image = document.getElementById('image');
    imageCount = imageCount + x;
    if(imageCount > total){imageCount = 1;}
    if(imageCount < 1){imageCount = total;} 
    image.src = "http://buhehe.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/"+ imageCount +".jpg";
    clearInterval(time);                                 
    time =  window.setInterval(function photoA() {       
    var image = document.getElementById('image');
    imageCount = imageCount + 1;
    if(imageCount > total){imageCount = 1;}
    if(imageCount < 1){imageCount = total;} 
    image.src = "http://buhehe.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/"+ imageCount +".jpg";
    },1000);
    }
 var time = window.setInterval(function photoA() {     
    var image = document.getElementById('image');
    imageCount = imageCount + 1;
    if(imageCount > total){imageCount = 1;}
    if(imageCount < 1){imageCount = total;} 
    image.src = "http://buhehe.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/"+ imageCount +".jpg";
    },2500);
```

CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   #image{
        width: 400px !important;
height:300px !important;
    }
  #slider {
        width: 400px !important;
height:300px !important;
    }
}
 @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   #image{
        width: 300px !important;
height:200px !important;
    }
  #slider {
        width: 300px !important;
height:200px !important;
    }
}
#slider {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: 3px;
 margin-top: 7px;
margin-bottom: 7px;
     padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    background: #eceded;

    border-radius: 7px;
    }
#image {
    width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
    }

.left {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:80%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left:15px;
    opacity:1;
    animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
    animation-delay: 2s;
  }
  .right {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:80%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right:15px;
    opacity:1;
    animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
    animation-delay: 2s;;
  }
.right:hover ,  .left:hover {
    opacity:0.6; cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Comment: You have no `@keyframes slide`, so you have no animation.

Comment: Hi Kosh, can you help me? I tried but no result. If can helpme to make simple aimation. please

Comment: Please read [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) and play with the examples there. Then try to implement something yourself and feel free to ask if you have any problems.

Comment: Also, you didn't apply the `animation` css to the image! (but you define it on your buttons)

Comment: should i apply it to csss or in JS?